# python regex: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
import re
def preprocessor(text):
    text = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', text)
    emoticons = re.findall('(?::|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\)|\(|D|P)', text)
    text = re.sub('[\W]+', ' ', text.lower()) + \'.join(emoticons).replace('-', '')
    return text
```

I am getting an error in line 5 saying "unexpected character after line continuation character". Please, somebody help me out.

Comment: The last line of your function makes no sense to me.  Please show sample text and the output you expect.  There may be a better way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Your `join()` statement is not properly formed.  Because you have a bare `\`, the interpreter thinks you're invoking the line continuation character, e.g.:

```
print("a \
b")
# a b
```

If you want to join on `\`, use:

```
print("\\".join(['a','b'])) 
# a\b
```

In your case:

```
 '\\'.join(emoticons)
```